# How do I add a label to wxWidgets wxBitmapButton?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

How do I create a button using wxWidgets that has both a label(text) and an image or icon. If I select wxBitmapButton there is a field called "label". But whenever I write anything in that field it doesn't update code in the wxFormBuilder. I have also tried wxButton->SetLabel() but no luck.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do this in wxWidgets 2.9.1 or greater and can use either a wxBitmapButton or wxButton. To quote from the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_button.html):

> Since version 2.9.1 wxButton supports showing both text and an image
>   (currently only when using wxMSW, wxGTK or wxOSX/Cocoa ports), see
>   SetBitmap() and SetBitmapLabel(), SetBitmapDisabled() methods. In
>   the previous wxWidgets versions this functionality was only available
>   in (the now trivial) wxBitmapButton class which was only capable of
>   showing an image without text.

Comment: Upgrading to the wx2.9 series does get you quite a lot of improvements. If you need a work around you could always add the text to your image...

Comment: Yea I think its better if I just upgrade, better for the long run. Thanks for your help! Should I mark this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Given that it seems to have answered your question it would be nice :)